# Add custom field in product's custom option

Tags: php, magento-1.9

Any help would be appreciated,
I want to add Custom field while adding product custom option
for e.g title,Price etc 
[image: Please see this screen shot, This is the content from "Custom option" tab in the product edit/add]

Comment: You will probably get more help if you make your post more than one sentence long. Maybe it is because I don't really have experience with magento, but I can't really understand what you are trying to do from what little you posted. Your sentence is a bit ungrammatical, which doesn't really help matters.

Answer (score 0):

Create a 4 fields table, with an Id (autoincrement), IdProduct (as foreign key to products), Custom (as String/Varchar), Value (as String/Varchar)

When you need information about one product, search form the IdProduct.
You will get some like:

```
+---------+--------------------+
| Custom  | Value              |
+---------+--------------------+
| Title   | NameOfTheProduct   |
| Weight  | 12.326             |
| Price   | 3.45               |
| Date    | 2015-01-20 01:02:03|
| ...     |                    |
+---------+--------------------+
```

Sometimes maybe you will need one more field to know how to convert the Values (String, Float, Date,...)

Answer (score 0):

megento_admin->catalog->attributes->manageAttributes
add attribute and then insert attribute in attribute set.
it will show in product insert

for more info : http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/catalog_product_set/index